# Bootstrap datetimepicker auto close not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've created two datetimepickers. Everything is working fine, only autoclose is not working (after date is selected from calendar).

Autoclose is one of the settings on both datetimepickers:

```
$('#dateFrom').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    minView: 2,
    maxView: 4,    
    autclose: true
  });

$('#dateTo').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    minView: 2,
    maxView: 4,    
    autclose: true
  });
```

Why it's not working?

Example is [here](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/OjPMPb?editors=1010)

Comment: Replace the autclose with autoclose please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be 'autoclose' instead of 'autclose'.

```
$('#dateFrom').datetimepicker({
   format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
   minView: 2,
   maxView: 4,    
   autoclose: true
});

$('#dateTo').datetimepicker({
   format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
   minView: 2,
   maxView: 4,    
   autoclose: true
});
```